# C# Paste clipboard content into DataTable

Tags: c#, text, datatable, clipboard, paste

Since I was unable to find a good method to paste clipboard text into a DataTable, I came up with this one. Hope to save someone's time.

Comment: If you have any issue with your code, i'd suggest to post it as a part of your question.

Comment: My intention was to share the working code I came up with with the community. But I'm not sure if I did it the proper way. If you or someone could guide me about the correct method, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

...

```
 private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert) || (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V))

        {
            pasteClipboardIntoDataTable(true);
        }
    }

    private void pasteClipboardIntoDataTable(Boolean createNewColumnsIfRequired)
    {
        if (!Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clipboard does not containt any text to paste.");
            return;
        }

        //Uses tab as the default separator, but if there's no tab, use the system's default

        String textSeparator = (Clipboard.GetText().Contains("\t")) ? "\t" : System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;

        List<String> clipboardAsList = new List<String>(Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n'));

        List<String[]> cleanLines = clipboardAsList
         .Select(s => s.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Split(textSeparator.ToCharArray()))
         .ToList<String[]>()
         ;

        foreach (String[] line in cleanLines)
        {
            if (createNewColumnsIfRequired && dataTable.Columns.Count < line.Length)
            {
                for (int i = dataTable.Columns.Count; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns.Add();
                }
            }

            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

            //If the clipboard contains too many columns and createNewColumnsIfRequired is false

            if (line.Length > dataRow.ItemArray.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The clipboard contains the following " + line.Length + " colums: \n\n" + string.Join(", " + Environment.NewLine, line) + ".\n\nBut the Datagrid only contains " + dataRow.ItemArray.Length + " columns.");                    
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                dataRow[i] = line[i];
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
```